# Why does logrotate zip a file before it is closed

Tags: logs, mysql, logrotate

I'm using logrotate to rotate mysql output.  When cron runs logrotate, I get frequently get an e-mail with the following content:

```
error: Compressing program wrote following message to stderr when compressing log /var/log/mysql/mysqld.err-20150408:
gzip: stdin: file size changed while zipping
```

indicating that after logrotate moved the file and called gzip on it, the file was still open and mysql was writing to it.  Here's my logrotate config for mysql:

```
/var/log/mysql/mysql.err /var/log/mysql/mysql.log /var/log/mysql/mysqld.err {
monthly
create 660 mysql mysql
notifempty
size 5M
sharedscripts
missingok
postrotate
[ -f /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ] && /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`
endscript
}
```

This is the unmodified file that is shipped with Gentoo's mysql package, so I doubt there are problems with it.  I have no trouble with other logs being rotated.

Any ideas what may be going on?

Comment: The title of your question may indicate a misconception. It's not `logrotate` that has to stop writing to the file and close it, it's whatever application is writing it, in this case MySQL.

Comment: You are right. I fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gzip error message states pretty much what is going on -- the file is being written to (by MySQL in this case) during compression. Try using `delaycompress` (with `compress`); from the man page:

> **delaycompress**
>
> Postpone compression of the previous log file to the next rotation
>   cycle. This only has effect when used in combination with compress. It
>   can be used when some program cannot be told to close its logfile and
>   thus might continue writing to the previous log file for some time.

Comment: OK, it does not clarify the issue, but it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful for me right now when I ran into similar problems with a different program (logs were not being rotated correctly, was seeing occurrences of this error in the log files)